# Does stopSelf() guarantee Service stopping (and HOW)? if so, is return required (in case stopSelf called internally)?

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

I Have questions about how `Service` and `IntentService` function. The points to ask about are below:

Does calling `stopSelf()` *manually* in `Service` (or `IntentService`) guarantee the service to stop?

If stopSelf() is called manually somewhere in the Service, will the code following the call be executed?

`// As I know, calling stopSelf() can stop code execution in case it throws an exception, else I can't find a logic for that.`

Comment: `return` from where?

Comment: return from the actual method (in case stopSelf() is called internally) / I'll correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does calling stopSelf() somewhere in Service (or IntentService) guarantee service to stop?

Yes, it does.

> And does a return statement mandatory to not execute code after stopSelf() call?

`return` is still needed if the function has a return type other than `void` (otherwise your code won't compile). The `return` statement most likely will be executed as `stopSelf()` results in stopping `Service` asynchronously.

> As I know, calling stopSelf() can stop code execution in case it throws an exception, else I can't find a logic for that.

By calling `stopSelf()` you notify the system that `Service` is done with its "job" so the system could release resources the `Service` is holding. This is very similar to execution of `Activity`'s `onBackPressed()` that is called when user presses the back button - the system finishes the `Activity` releasing resources.